# Finding a repeating set of strings among a larger set

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I see that in order to find repeating patterns of characters within a string or even between 2 strings, suffix trees are recommended. What I'm trying to do is slightly different.

I have a list of strings that are ordered in a list(by ordered I mean that the second string strictly comes after the first, the third comes after the second and so on). I'd like to find the repeating sets of strings of lengths 3-7 in the whole set of strings. What would be the data structure and algorithm of choice for this problem?

The count of the strings would be 15K at a minimum(and lets assume a maximum of 30K). The length of each string would be range from about 3-35 characters.

I'd like the strings in the first repeated subarray, and information on how many times the subarray repeats(I don't need the positions of the repetitions however) throughout the whole list.

An example :
["a", "b", "c", "g", "h", "t", "i", "a", "b","c", "z"]

Here Id expect the answer ["a", "b", "c"] when I pass require repeating strings of length of 3. This length might vary from 3-7.

Comment: depends on the search String Length and searchable length too

Comment: I've added in that information to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Rabin Karp Search Algorithm suits best according to me

Comment: What do you mean by **repeating sets of strings**? Could you give an example, if possible?

Comment: @Yuchen Thanks for your comment, I've made an edit with an example.

Comment: With your example, they don't have to be one-character strings, correct, they can be any length?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, order does matter.

Comment: And what about ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'abcdefg', 'h', 'i']? Is that repeating?

Comment: @Shashank Yes the example has 1 character, but as mentioned in the post their length can vary from 3-35 characters.

Comment: @Shashank No it is not.

Comment: Understood. Do you want the first repeated subarray, or a list of all repeated subarrays?

Comment: I'd like the strings in the first repeated subarray, and information on how many times the subarray repeats(I don't need the positions of the repetitions however) throughout the whole list.

Comment: I presume you don't want a bruteforce approach.

Comment: @uki Specify that in the question then. Sigh...

Comment: @uki, do you want the first repeated or all the repeated?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've edited the question to answer your query. "I'd like the strings in the first repeated subarray, and information on how many times the subarray repeats(I don't need the positions of the repetitions however) throughout the whole list."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finds the first repeater and how often it occurred:

```
from collections import Counter
def repeater(strings, k):
    ctr = Counter()
    first = None
    for i in range(len(strings) - k + 1):
        seq = tuple(strings[i:i+k])
        if seq in ctr and first is None:
            first = seq
        ctr[seq] += 1
    return first, ctr.get(first)

seq, ctr = repeater(["a", "b", "c", "g", "h", "t", "i", "a", "b","c", "z", "g", "h", "t"], 3)
if ctr:
    print(seq, 'occurred', ctr, 'times')
```

Prints:

```
('a', 'b', 'c') occurred 2 times
```

An alternative without `Counter`:

```
def repeater(strings, k):
    seen = set()
    rep, ctr = None, None
    for i in range(len(strings) - k + 1):
        seq = tuple(strings[i:i+k])
        if rep:
            ctr += seq == rep
        elif seq in seen:
            rep, ctr = seq, 2
        else:
            seen.add(seq)
    return rep, ctr
```

Comment: @uku I just added a solution for the updated question.